# display: none doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have web app for making music from javascript. But I have problem with `display: none` of my `.musicBox` class.

Here are the index.html code with all important styles & scripts.

[My index.html file on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNjjJv)

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
      .rotateDevice {
          display: block; 
      }
      .toneBox {
          display: none;
      }
  }
```

When I resize the window to under `520px` width it will 'display: none' my color Boxes. But why it didn't?

Comment: Closing this since it's a typo : line 162, you have a `.a` with no brackets.

Comment: there are link in the question...

Comment: Thanks Karl-Andre! That is my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something missing above this media query.

Remove the `.a` above it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.toneBox {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this may be it would help you:

```
Visibility: none;
```